# Django 1.10 - Multiple Table Inheritance vs Single model with 'type'

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication, django-1.10

Basically, I'm trying to build an authentification system using django's authentification support. I would need 2 different user types, TypeA and typeB for example. They should register through different routes, each one containing many different fields and few similar (email & password). Both of them will login through a single sign in route. 
What do you think would be the best approach to achieve this? Multiple Table Inheritance or a single model with type attribute ? (you can suggest other options too, I have no problem with that)
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
One question. I implemented both of the one-to-one relations for each user type, but now I‘m stuck at AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings. What should it‘s value be? Can it be declared 2 times for each one-to-one relation?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow but I would implement a user profile model with a one-to-one relation to User, instead of defining a custom user model.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll go on and try your method.